# How to turn off animation while navigating browser's history

Tags: macos, safari, multi-touch

Is there is any way to turn off animation while navigating through pages in safari (using one finger  swipe left/right gesture)?

I know, that it is a subtle different thing comparing to what we've accustomed to call navigation, since clicking back/forward history buttons works as expected.

But as for me, it is really annoying, eye straining and time consuming - to see animation each time you use mouse gestures to navigate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply disable scroll-to-navigate in the mouse/trackpad preferences, and instead use the two-finger swipe (or three, on a trackpad).

[image]

Comment: oh, that's great!

Comment: @shabunc: Note the third option gives you the best of both worlds: you can use the pretty animations when you want them, and not when you don't (or in apps that don't support it).